# How to implement a constructor for a generic type

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I haven't done much by way of writing my own generic classes, but I'm trying to make my own ArrayStack class and having trouble understanding how to correctly write the constructor.

```
public class ArrayStack<T> implements List<T> {

   private T[] a;
   private int n;

   public ArrayStack(T[] a) {
      this.a = a;
   }
}
```

And my main class that uses it:

```
public class ArrayStackTester {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayStack<Integer> numbers = new ArrayStack<Integer>();
   }
}
```

This produces a compilation error which says that `The ArrayStack<Integer> is undefined`, so I obviously suspect a problem with the constructor in the `ArrayStack` class.

I didn't include all the overriden `List` methods for brevity.

Comment: You need to define a no-args constructor, if you want to use one.

Comment: Your only constructor `public ArrayStack(T[] a) {` expects `T[]` array, which in your case is `Integer[]`. Where is this array?

Comment: classic compilation-error. the actual problem is way simpler: the constructor `ArrayStack()` isn't defined. You only defined the constructor `ArrayStack(T[])`

Comment: Thanks @Paul I missed the simplicity there because of my confusion with properly writing the constructor with defining the generics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining this no-args constructor first:

```
public ArrayStack() {
}
```

Or alternatively, pass along an array of the right type:

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[100];
ArrayStack<Integer> numbers = new ArrayStack<Integer>(array);
```

Comment: I guess my confusion is with the generics.  The constructor doesn't need to match the class definition?  `public ArrayStack<T>() {}`

Comment: @inquisitor you're calling a no-args constructor, hence you need to define  one first. It has nothing to do with generics.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez thanks and I see that now.  I was confused because of the syntax of how a generic class is defined.  I thought the constructor definition had to match that.  My missing the args was a separate but important issue.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

You defined one constructor, which takes a `T[]`. Then you tried to call a constructor which has no arguments. You need to define the constructor for `new ArrayStack<Integer>()` to do what you need it to do.

```
public ArrayStack() {
    // Initialize a (and possibly n) here as appropriate)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the ArrayStack class compiled?
There is a generic array, which causes troubles
[How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)